# rails form_tag redirecting to /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i was wondering why does

```
<%= form_tag( { :action => "/search", :method => "get" }, :class => "span4" ) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

give the following error?

```
No route matches [POST] "/assets"
```

i notice it's because of the /search. if i rewrote the code as...

```
<%= form_tag( { :action => "search", :method => "get" }, :class => "span4" ) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

without the /search, it correctly calls my controller method. can someone explain why? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you mean:

```
<%= form_tag( "/search", :method => "get" , :class => "span4" ) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

If the first parameter of `form_tag` is a hash as you have given, it is passed behind-the-scenes to `url_for`, which inteprets `:action` as the action part of a route for it to reverse-map.

Since you (I guess) want to just pass a plain URL, just pass it as a string for the first arg.

More info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) of course :)

Answer (score 1):

the ":action" should receive a name of "action", such as: "create", "update", or "destroy"

```
:action => "/search"
```

here the "/search"  is not a name, but an "url", which is not legal.

btw, I suggest you use xx_url instead of { :action => "", :controller => ""}, e.g.

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" %>
```

or

```
# you defined "search_path" in config/routes.rb
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => "get" %>
```

Comment: thanks so much!
i think it probably will be better to just change to search_path since it does what i want too